# MOSFET Differential Amplifier voltages via PSpice and by hand

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, pspice

I want to do an analysis on a differential pair and there is  a problem when the pair is in common-mode, at least that's what PSpice says. I find that \$V_{DS}\$ of both MOSFETs is 1.1V and PSpice agrees. However \$V_{GS}\$ is different than my calculations. Here is my circuit:

[image]

We have W/L = 10 and my model is the following:

```
.model nch nmos LEVEL=1 TOX=25 VTO=0.5 KP=140.0e-6 LAMBDA=0.1 PHI=0.6
```

Am I using the right transistors for this? I calculate \$V_{GS}\$ = 0.594 V. Also since it's an identical pair, shouldn't the voltage at the common-node at the source be 0 and not 98.51mV?

Comment: You didn't specify the W/L relationship in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the W/L relationship in the model.
If i calculate it with W/L = 1, it gives the same value as the simulator.

\$ V_{gs} = \sqrt{\frac{2I_D}{K_p\frac{W}{L}(1+V_{ds}\lambda)}} + V_{th} = \sqrt{\frac{2\cdot 7uA}{140uA/V^2\cdot\frac{1}{1}\cdot(1+1V\cdot0.1)}} + 0.5V = 801.5mV \$

And no, you can't assume that the source node is at 0V, it depends on how you drive the inputs. Also, in the real world there is no ideal current sources, so the source can never be 0V in that case.

Comment: You're right I was thinking about that but didn't know how to specify it since I just started using this program and info online is scarce. But the voltage at the source is correct right? We can assume that 0.09851V << 0.9V right so it's a virtual short.

Comment: @user3601507: You can specify it with the parameters W and L, like `W=10um, L=1um` which you add to you model definition. 

No, you can not always assume the source node is 0V, it depends on how you drive the inputs. Also, in the real world where you dont have ideal current sources, the source will never be 0V.

Comment: If it's in common-mode shouldn't it be very close to 0?

Comment: @user3601507: No. You have already set up the schematic, go see for yourself. Do a parametric sweep on the common mode voltage source V1, from like 0.9V to 1.8V in steps of 0.1V and plot the source node voltage.

Comment: You have a fixed current running through the pair(7uA each), which means the Vgs has to be the same all the time. So if you increase Vg, ultimatively Vs has to move also to keep the same gate to source voltage.